# Wrong type to apply?

Tags: scheme

I've been playing with Scheme for about 10 minutes and stumbled across this error:

```
scheme@(guile-user) [2]> (define (a one two) ((* one two)))
scheme@(guile-user) [2]> (a 2 3)
ERROR: In procedure 6:
ERROR: Wrong type to apply: 6
```

I was expecting this to return 6. How does "apply" enter into this?
What does this error mean?

Comment: Try [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), in particular the chapter about [evaluation](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parentheses in Scheme are not just a grouping construct. They generally mean function application.

The error is related to the body of your `define`. Specifically,

```
((* one two))
```

means

> Call the result of multiplying one by two

The JS equivalent is something like

```
function a (one, two) { (one * two)(); }
```

You most likely meant to define that function as

```
(define (a one two) (* one two))
```

which is just the multiplication, and should work fine.

Comment: This is much simpler and does the same: `(define a *)`